# Postfix relay smtp to 2 relayhosts for same domain

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

have a setup in which Postfix relays mail for a specific domain to another mail server (Exchange) via the usual transport file:

# /etc/postfix/main.cf

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

# /etc/postfix/transport

blah.local  smtp:[192.168.2.11]

So email for anything@blah.local coming into Postfix will be relayed to the Exchange Server at 192.168.2.11.

The Exchange will be replaced soon with something else though, hence I want to test another server in addition to the Exchange, i.e. I want to relay all mails to blah.local to TWO servers at the same time. No failover or load balance, but mail to blah.local relayed to 2 relayhosts at the same time.
have been researching this but don't think this is possible with Postfix alone. Ideas anyone?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's happen to the email when exchange server accept the email but the other one reject it?

Comment: No there is no server rejecting it, but the problem is that I don't know how to configure Postfix so that it relays mail for blah.local to two servers at the same time.

Comment: You need to use combination of three postfix rewriting parameters: *recipient_bcc_maps, transport_maps, smtp_generic_maps*. See this similar case: [How to test and actually perform a transfer of an internet domain to a new server regarding mail?](http://serverfault.com/questions/395661/how-to-test-and-actually-perform-a-transfer-of-an-internet-domain-to-a-new-serve/474857#474857)

Comment: Thanks, yeah ok I was looking for a way to setup two relay destinations, but in fact you are right, this combination of recipient_bcc_maps, transport_maps and smtp_generic_maps will work for me for testing a new server without interrupting the old server in any way. Many thanks for pointing that out!